# Editing WFS-T polygon layer gives me random geometry shape instead of current displayed geometry

Tags: postgis, geoserver, editing, wfs-t

I have this setup:

1-Postgis polygon layer

2-Published layer in Geoserver (granted access to everyone)

3-Configured workspace for all possible services including WFS-T

4-Disabled cached layer capabilities in Geoserver for layers that will be edited just to be sure that the geometry doesn't mess up geometry with any cached version

4-Using mapstore2 as frontend web client for viewing and editing data.

**Issue:**
When i start editing the current layer the highlighted geometry for editing is different than it is currently displayed. Look like it is generalized and messed up and not topologically connected with neighbors. The bad part is that it is not even just displayed but it also snaps only to those vertices that are badly highlighted.

[image: Highlighted with yellow color]

Yellow color Highlighted polygon for editing, black color is the current polygon geometry. The difference is very obviously and it happens on every selected polygon, it just gets some random geometry shape.

Comment: Is there a primary key on the table?

Comment: Yes, with the field name gid. But i haven't tick the option expose in primary key in geoserver during layer publish. Is this something needed?

Comment: Can you compare the gid of the polygon in the map and in the selection? Also, can you add the WKT for the original and the selection

Comment: It is the same.

Comment: Then we need to see the WKT